# when simplifying algebraic fractions do you go into negative powers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When simplifying algebraic fractions such as in the fraction $\frac{5p^2q}{10pq^2}$ do you go into negative powers such as stated in the rules of indices or leave it so that for this example the denominator q cancels out the numerator q and is left raised to the power of 1.

Comment: There is no rule. For me simplification means that you write it with as few as possible symbols. It is a mater of personal taste if you want to keep the fraction or not, you still say the same.

Comment: I guess it boils down to taste: $0.5 p q^{-1}$ or $1/2 p/q$ or $p/2q$ etc. The first would be most suitable if writing a document and don't want to create a wider interline to allow the space for a fraction. Usually, I prefer non-negative power

Comment: Well, clearly we cancel out the 5, a p, and q to get $\frac {p}{2q}$ and whether your write this as $\frac p{2q}$ or $\frac 12\frac pq$ or $\frac 12pq^{-1}$ or  $2^{-1}pq^{-1}$ or $0.5pq^{-1}$ etc, is a matter of taste, circumstance, practicality and what exactly the nature of the question was.

Comment: Well, the question is "simplify".  I'd consider $\frac 1q$ to be "simpler" then $q^{-1}$ but if I were forced to debate some-one as to *why* I make that value judgement I may not when the argument.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context.

I would go as far as $$\frac{5p^2q}{10pq^2} = \frac{p}{2q}$$

but I do not go any further to write it is $(1/2) pq^{-1}$